# How to change image and text on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to change the image and text on hover and I have got [this in codepen](http://codepen.io/jordharris6/pen/VpEzEG/) but it doesnt seem to be working?

```js
$(".service_1").hover(function() {
  $(".hello").hide();

  $(".text").append("<span class='go'>Appended text</span>");
});
```

```css
.service_item img {
  position: absolute;
}

.service_item {
  height: 307px;
  width: 700px;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: background-image 0.5s linear;
  -webkit-transition: background-image 0.5s linear;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.service_item:hover {
  transition: background-image 0.5s linear;
  -webkit-transition: background-image 0.5s linear;
}

.serviceimg {
  margin-top: 66px;
  height: 949px;
}

.service_item a {
  height: 50%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
}

.service_item img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

.service_item img:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

.service_item span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="service_item service_1">
  <a href="/uk-marriage-spouse-civil-partner-visa/">
    <img src="http://www.edwards-immigration.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/mikhail-pavstyuk-8436.png">
    <img src="http://www.edwards-immigration.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Untitled-1.png">
    <div class="text"><span class="hello">Hello there</span></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Can someone point me to where im going wrong please?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When posting questions, please remember to include the code itself in your question, instead of simply linking it to an external service. You might also have realised that you cannot post the link without posting the code: the rule is in place to ensure that the question on StackOverflow can stand on itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Css can handle what you are trying to achieve. Here is a working example using `css transitions` and `flex-box` to align your text:

```css
.service_item img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.service_item {
  height: 307px;
  width: 700px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.serviceimg {
  margin-top: 66px;
  height: 949px;
}

.service_item a {
  height: 307px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.service_item img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

.service_item:hover img:last-of-type {
  opacity: 0;
}

.service_item:hover .append-text {
  opacity: 1;
}

.append-text {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="service_item service_1">
  <a href="/uk-marriage-spouse-civil-partner-visa/">
    <img src="http://www.edwards-immigration.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/mikhail-pavstyuk-8436.png">
    <img src="http://www.edwards-immigration.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Untitled-1.png">
    <div class="hello">Hello there</div>
    <div class="append-text">APPENDED TEXT</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#">
<img src="http://www.dummy.com/icons/fasticon/angry-birds/128/yellow-bird-icon.png" 
onmouseover="this.src='http://www.dummy.com/icons/fasticon/angry-birds/128/red-bird-icon.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://www.dummy.com/icons/fasticon/angry-birds/128/yellow-bird-icon.png'"
border="0" alt=""/></a>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Will surely do that @RoryMcCrossan from next. Front-end is not my area of working. Had implemented it once during my college project so remember. Anyway thanks for pointing out :)